# Vue test utils how to change select value with v-model

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, testing, vue-test-utils

Hello I would like to check what happens after changing the value of select inside of the test.I'm using `vue-test-utils`.
Currently I'm unable to check if the select emitted the input event. I'm using Buefy select component if that matters.

The html part of component

```html
<b-select
  v-model="workHoursType"
>
  <option :value="WORKING_HOURS_PERIOD.daily">{{daily}}</option>
  <option :value="WORKING_HOURS_PERIOD.weekly">{{weekly}}</option>
</b-select>
```

Test, which is failing due to `undefined` is emitted

```js
it("once working hours type is set to daily, the hours per week should have no value", async () => {
    const wrapper = createWrapper();

    const options = wrapper.find("select").findAll("option");
    await options.at(1).setSelected();

    await flushPromises();

    expect(wrapper.emitted().input).toBeDefined();
  });
```

I've seen also different approach for `v-model` based components however it still doesnt work for me.

```js
it("with v-model", async () => {
    const wrapper = createWrapper();

    const select = wrapper.find("select");
    const option = wrapper.findAll("option").at(0);
    option.element.selected = true;
    select.trigger("change");

    await flushPromises();

    expect(wrapper.emitted().input).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Comment: Do you solve it or found a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: @PeterIvanoff not exactly but I end up with setting it with `select.setValue(1)` and checking `wrapper.vm` values. Not perfect, but you can check if Vuex call mutations with expected values if you are using it with select.

Comment: I also found cause, event emitted only if the specific conditions are match. It was my mistake. Thanks for respond!